# Value not updating using angular.merge()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a default Object which has all the parameter listed. Now I give the user a right to list some parameters and get it working, the others would be defaulted as mentioned by me. 
The issue is I am not getting it to work in a directive using angular's deep copy solution i.e. angular.merge()
You can see the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/saras_arya/zpqum1y8/).
The issue is in these lines.

```
console.log(scope.options);
scope.options = angular.merge(defaultOptions,scope.options);
console.log(scope.options);
```

Now if you see in console the both the scope.options are different, it shouldn't be the case. 
How do I resolve this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have noticed, but you are merging an array (`$scope.options`) with an object literal (`defaultOptions`). Try changing `$scope.options` to an object and you will get the desired behaviour, at least what you asked for.

Fiddle [updated](https://jsfiddle.net/zpqum1y8/10/).

Comment: don't :-) happens all the time. Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Why they should be different? You are **merging** them.

You are merging **defaultOptions** in **scope.options**.

In your example i assume you want to make **defaultOptions** === **scope.options**, so if you want to make copy using merge you need to

```
delete scope.options;
```

Here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apimenov93/nk15syv2/2/)